# Synchronizing class diagrams in ARGOUML

Tags: uml, argouml

Working with ARGOUML how do i transfer specific class diagrams from one workstation to another.

Both workstations have the same project running only that each project has different class diagrams.

Need to sync

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a much more appropriate question for one of the ArgoUML user forums (e.g. mailing list or bulletin board).

Clearly if the two projects have different diagrams, they are **not** the same project despite your assertion.  ArgoUML only allows one project to be open at a time, so there's no way within ArgoUML to cut/paste among projects.

If no changes have been made to the model, it may be possible to unzip the project, move a diagram file by hand, update the table of contents, and rezip things, but it might be easier to just recreate the diagram by hand.  Diagramming in ArgoUML is pretty quick.